# <Error from server: code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:57 no viable alternative at input ';' (...,vendedor, total) VALUES ([;])">

Tags: python, cassandra

I'm trying to insert data from a .csv file into cassandra by python. my code is reading this list and is connected to Cassandra, but when inserting, it gives the error: cassandra.protocol.SyntaxException: <Error from server: code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 1:57 no viable alternative at input ';' (...,seller, total) VALUES ([;])">. I printed the query to see errors and it returns something strange.

```
for j in lista_arq2:
      query1 = "INSERT INTO vendas (nota_fiscal,vendedor, total) VALUES "+ j + ";"
      print(query1)
      session.execute(query1)
```

query printed returning:

```
INSERT INTO vendas (nota_fiscal,vendedor, total) VALUES (;
```

I'm not understanding why it's not bringing the complete query. the keyspace is already created in cassanda, as well as the table "vendas". One data has already been manually entered successfully as a test using this query:

```
query = "INSERT INTO vendas (nota_fiscal, vendedor,total) VALUES (000, 'Jake Peralta',300.00)"
```

Comment: it's really better to use prepared statements that will handle correct escaping of strings, etc. See the doc for more information: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.25/getting_started/#prepared-statement

Comment: I'll need to learn more about Datastax. I don't know how to use it. So, I'm trying without it. But thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, after trying all day, I found a way using Pandas to insert all the data from the .csv file: treatment using pd.Dataframe and a "for" inserting item by item, as below:

```
tabela = pd.DataFrame(lista_arq2)
tabela.columns = ['nota_fiscal', 'vendedor', 'total']
       print(tabela)          
        
for i, j in tabela.iterrows():
       item = "{},'{}',{}".format(j.nota_fiscal, j.vendedor,j.total)    
       query1 = "INSERT INTO vendas (codigo,nota_fiscal,vendedor, total) VALUES (uuid(),"+ item + ");"
                session.execute(query1)
```

that way the data was included in Cassandra perfectly.